# Install Tidy, PHP

Tags: php, tidy

I guess when php was installed on my box --with-tidy arg was not included.

When browsing my php.ini the line:

```
;extension=php_tidy.dll
```

is missing.

How can I add the module to my php install? Note I tried adding:

```
extension=php_tidy.dll
```

but with no luck.

I checked the docs but all they say is:

> This extension is bundled with PHP 5 and greater, and is installed using the --with-tidy configure option.

Comment: I'd assume you either supply php_tidy.dll or compile php --with-tidy alltogether. I might be wrong though

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I was having the same trouble, and wrote up my solution here:
[Installing Tidy 2.0 PHP extension on Ubuntu 10.10](http://web.onassar.com/blog/2010/11/16/installing-tidy-2-0-php-extension-on-ubuntu-10-10/)
http://web.onassar.com/blog/2010/11/16/installing-tidy-2-0-php-extension-on-ubuntu-10-10/

It works on newer versions of Ubuntu as well.
While it may not be the most direct route, it works well.
I hope it helps others.

Comment: This should work for ubuntu these days:

sudo apt-get install php5-tidy

Comment: /*install php5-tidy. Example (for Debian and all:),*/ sudo apt-get install php5-tidy ; /*relaod apache 2*/ : sudo service apache2 reload

Comment: I found this answer resulted in errors on the make step.

Answer (score 18):

On Ubuntu, you can add tidy to your php5 installation by running this command in a terminal:

```
$ sudo apt-get install php5-tidy
```

If you want to check if it is already installed or validate that the command above worked:

```
$ php -i | grep libTidy
libTidy Release => 25 March 2009 // means tidy is installed
```

To install both php5 and tidy at the same time, use this command (as an alternative to the "--with-tidy" configuration option):

```
$ sudo apt-get install php5 php5-tidy
```

Comment: The `apt` was good, work fine, but how to enable? `php -i` show nothing.

Comment: Hi, the 2017 problem: `apt install php7.1-tidy`  for PHP 7.1... It **is not `php7.0-tidy`** (!). The apt and `php -i` **say nothing** about that you try to use wrong version.

Answer (score 10):

For PHP 7 just run

```
sudo apt-get install php-tidy
```

And restart Apache, That's it :)

---

Update: Thanks to @Arnis Juraga

For the version above PHP 7, you can mention the version code as follows.
`apt-get install php7.4-tidy`

Comment: `E: Unable to locate package php-tidy` EDIT: never mind me, PHP needs to be installed first obviously :)

Comment: For php7 versions, run `apt-get install php7.4-tidy` and `phpenmod tidy`

Answer (score 2):

Put that line in php.ini next to the other `extension=...dll` lines and make sure `php_tidy.dll` is in the directory configured in php.ini under `extension_dir`.

Comment: Where could one get that `php_tidy.dll` (except compiling it from source)?

Answer (score 2):

In ubuntu: you need to run the following command in terminal

> sudo apt-get install php5-tidy
>
> > and the restart the server
> >
> > > sudo service apache2 restart.

Comment: Or with systemd: `systemctl restart apache2`.

Answer (score 1):

For those who are having trouble enabling Tidy extension for PHP (using PHP handler for Apache server) on **Windows** (WAMP server), please note that you may be editing the wrong **php.ini** file. Assuming that WAMP server is installed in **C:\wamp[ver]\** where **[ver]** is a variable version number.

File that you're probably editing:

```
C:\wamp[ver]\bin\php\php[ver]\php.ini
```

File that you must edit:

```
C:\wamp[ver]\bin\apache\apache[ver]\bin\php.ini
```

You also might want to make sure what's the correct php.ini file to edit by creating an info php file and add this code to it:

```
<?php phpinfo();
```

Then look for **Loaded Configuration File** string.

Finally make sure you uncomment this line within the correct php.ini file:

```
extension=tidy
```