# Can I configure PHP to automatically format the HTML it generates?

Tags: php

For example…

This PHP code

```
<?php
echo '<html>';
echo '<body>';
echo '<h1>Header One</h1>';
echo '<p>Hello World!</p>';
echo '</body>';
echo '</html>';
?>
```

Generates this HTML markup

```
<html><body><h1>Header One</h1><p>Hello World!</p></body></html>
```

Are there any functions, libraries or configuration options to make PHP automatically apply some simple formatting (line breaks & indentation) based on the nesting of html tags generated in the output? So that instead something like this would be generated…

```
<html>
      <body>
            <h1>Header One</h1>
            <p>Hello World!</p>
      </body>
</html>
```

Comment: [PHP Tidy](http://php.net/manual/en/book.tidy.php) does this.

Comment: Why are you echo'ing the HTML markup? You can just type it outside of PHP tags

Comment: Or, use a HEREDOC and format it yourself instead of echoing each line...

Comment: The code I am working on generates a lot of html inside loops, and is much more complicated than the example code. I just wanted something simple to explain my question.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to properly indent PHP/HTML mixed code?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1155799/how-to-properly-indent-php-html-mixed-code)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do this (my preference):

```
<html>
      <body>
            <h1>Header One</h1>
            <p>Hello World!</p>
            <?php echo '<p>Hello Hello!</p>'; ?>
      </body>
</html>
```

Or:

```
<?php

$html = '<html><body><h1>Header One</h1><p>Hello World!</p></body></html>';

$tidy = new tidy();
$tidy->parseString($html, array('indent'=> true,'output-xhtml'=> true), 'utf8');
$tidy->cleanRepair();

echo $tidy;

?>";
```

...would print:

```
<html>
      <body>
            <h1>Header One</h1>
            <p>Hello World!</p>
      </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'm just curious if there is a way to have PHP do the work for me. I understand I can manually add the formatting and break in and out of PHP.

Comment: @Corey The last example uses `tidy` which will format the xhtml for you as original request. Read more: http://www.php.net/manual/en/tidy.examples.basic.php

Answer (score 3):

You could try templating engines like [Smarty](http://www.smarty.net/), [Savant](http://phpsavant.com/), [PHP Sugar](http://php-sugar.net/) or [VLib](http://vlib.clausvb.de/vlibtemplate.php).

Or you could go commando with [output handling](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php) (which I think is a hack). `ob_start('ob_tidyhandler');`

*For the output handling, Tidy might not be installed or enabled, typically the [package you will need to install is named `php-tidy`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42597953/10981125) and you will need to uncomment `extension=tidy` in your php.ini*

Comment: +1 for actually answering the question, rather than going on a rant :)

Comment: Nice nice. `ob_tidyhandler` is new one to me. Nice!

Answer (score 1):

You can put html in your PHP script without having to echo it. You also might want to look for a PHP template engine like [smarty](http://www.smarty.net/), so you can separate the view from logic.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer to use [heredoc strings](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc) and format/indent the HTML myself.  Mixing HTML strings inside PHP code quickly leads to unreadable, unmaintainable code.  Some advantages of this method:

- Quotes don't need to be escaped.
- You can put variables inside the heredoc strings.
- Even when working with code that loops, you can output the HTML inside heredoc strings.  If these strings are indented properly relative to your other blocks of HTML, you will still get HTML code that has good indentation.
- It forces you to think about when you want to print HTML, and to print it in blocks instead of lots of little pieces sprinkled throughout your code (very hard to read and maintain).

It's better to separate the PHP code from the HTML as much as you can, whether this means using a templating engine or just putting all of the code before all of the HTML.  However, there are still times when it's easiest to mix PHP and HTML.

Here's an example:

```
<?php
$text = 'Hello World!';
echo <<<HTML
<html>
    <body>
        <h1>Header One, with some '"quotes"'</h1>
        <p>$text</p>
    </body>
</html>

HTML;
?>
```

Comment: I'm just curious if there is a way to have PHP do the work for me. I understand I can manually add the formatting and break in and out of PHP.

Comment: Corey: I'd look into `ob_tidyhandler` then, but this feels like a hack to me.  Doing the formatting yourself leads to much cleaner code, which I think is very important for readability and maintainability.  Getting and learning a good editor that understands indentation makes this easier.

Comment: "Mixing HTML strings inside PHP code quickly leads to unreadable, unmaintainable code." and yet `Heredoc` is esoteric and often _less_ readable than simply `?>` escaping back to HTML. It _might_ be beneficial if you need to embed a lot of `$variables` and don't want to use `<?= $shortTags ?>`, but it doesn't seem to be something that should be used without good reason, when better ways are available.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question right, you want to pretty-print the HTML output.

This can be done by post-processing the output of your PHP script. Either by using PHP's output handling feature combined with the [tidy extension<sup>*­Docs*</sup>](http://php.net/manual/en/book.tidy.php):

```
ob_start('ob_tidyhandler');
```

Tidy is an extension specialized on cleaning up HTML code, changing indentation etc.. But it's not the only way.

Another alternative is to delegate the post-processing task to the webserver, e.g. [output filters in Apache HTTP Server<sup>*­Docs*</sup>](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/filter.html).

Comment: could you expand on Tidy? is that line of code the only thing needed, or is there more to it?

Comment: That single line of code is initiatializing the output handling callback. See [`ob_tidyhandler`](http://php.net/ob_tidyhandler) and [`ob_start`](http://php.net/ob_start). I'm a bit unsure how to configure the tidy handler options from top of my head. You can also create your own handler, buffer and process the buffer with the tidy functions.

Answer (score 0):

...Or you can use the "<<<" operator where you can set formation by yourself:

```
<?php

echo <<<DATA
<html>
      <body>
            <h1>Header One</h1>
            <p>Hello World!</p>
      </body>
</html>
DATA;
```

Comment: Nothing wrong with this answer.  In fact I use this technique in my own code because it forces you to think about when you want to print HTML, and to print it in blocks instead of lots of little pieces sprinkled throughout your code (very hard to read and maintain).

Answer (score 0):

If the below code looks useful to generate html with php, try this library 
https://github.com/raftalks/Form

```
Html::make('div', function($html))
{
    $html->table(function($table)
    {
        $table->thead(function($table)
        {
            $table->tr(function($tr)
            {
                $tr->th('item');
                $tr->th('category');
            });
        });


        $table->tr(function($tr)
        {   
            $tr->td()->ng_bind('item.name','ng-bind');
            $tr->td()->ng_bind('item.category','ng-bind');

            $tr->setNgRepeat('item in list','ng-repeat'); //using second parameter to force the attribute name.
        });

        $table->setClass('table');
    });

   $html->setClass('tableContainer');
});
```